# write data from an arraylist of objects and arraylist within objects to a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

say i have a an arraylist that contains objects of type employee that have instance variables such as id,first name, last name, tel and also with each object there is another arraylist that contains numerical data and I want to write all that data out to a txt file , what would be the best way of doing this

My current thinking is that I could iterate through with a for loop the first arraylist to write the instance variables, then have a inner for loop to make get calls to the arraylist in the objects. I have got the first for loop working and writing, just trying to work out how to get the second inner loop to get the other data.
It is important that the data is written in the correct order which is id, firstname, lastname, tel and then followed by the numerical data in the order it is stored, then on to the next employee to write in the same order.

Im not sure how how to achieve this exactly and am still experimenting with the code but would appreciate to suggestions on how best to go about this.

UPDATE

Seems like I have it working - i did the following:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream("output.txt")); 
    for (int a=0;a<emp.size();a++)
    {
    empNumber = emp.get(a).empNumber;
    out.println(empNumber); 
    fName = emp.get(w).fName;
    out.println(fName); 
    lName = emp.get(w).lName;
    out.println(lName); 
    telNum = emp.get(w).telNum;
        for (int l=0;l<emp.get(w).dataNums.size();l++)
        {
            out.println(emp.get(w).dataNums.get(l));
        }

    out.close();    
    }
```

There are probably much more sophisticated ways but Im happy enough as a beginner I worked it out myself.

thanks for the replies though

Comment: Your current thinking seems to be on the right track. What specifically are you having a problem with? Are your experiments failing to produce correct results? Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Show code constructing those *ArrayList* instances.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the current way you're doing. you could also use an iterator design pattern for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKIzUuMdmag

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is to implement a toString() method for each one of your objects. Then just  use toString() on your arrayList with employee. And lastly use for example fileWriter to write this String to a txt.